# Как организовать резервный канал для VPN-подключения?

Tags: windows, vpn, сервер

Имеем такую карту сети:

```
                  ↔ Dlink Dir 100(optic)↔| Inet | ↔ Клиентская сетьWin2k3serv ↔ switch                  ↔ Dlink2500U(ADSL)    ↔| Inet |
```

Пояснения: Клиенты подключаются через VPN к серверу для работы в 1С.

Вопрос: Как можно организовать автоматический переход VPN на резервный канал, чтобы это было незаметно для пользователей?

Если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте, буду уточнять.

**UPD:** поясняю суть проблемы с точки зрения "клиента": подключаемся к серверу через VPN и работаем в 1С.     *обрыв связи/провайдер начал какие-то тех.работы* ``Невозможно подключиться. Пищат пользователи...

**UPD2:** Интересует возможность автоматического переключения между каналами, используя только возможности сервера; и каким образом это можно сделать? А также как это повлияет на пользователей, подключающихся по VPN?(Понятно, что будут внешние IP разные. Из этого возникает вопрос: можно ли и с этим что-то сделать?)

Comment: Что за коммутатор (switch). Управляемый ли? Поддерживает ли STP?

Comment: Коммутатор неуправляемый http://dlink.ru/ru/products/1/1373.html [D-link DES 1024A]

Comment: Я правильно понял что Клиентская сеть подключена к двум провайдерам?!

Comment: pyatak, Клиентская сеть - это образно. На самом деле Клиентов много и они меня мало интересуют.Сервер подключен к интернету 2-мя разными провайдерами(соответственно разные внешние IP). Вот резервирование подключения к нему нужно сделать.

Comment: Ну ок, а почему бы не разрулить DNS-ом?

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, конкретнее? Добавить альтернативный DNS?Если "да", то тогда на клиентах надо будет делать 2-ое подключение к VPNу?

Comment: Вы делаете DNS запись, site.my.org, и пихаете в нее 2 ip, тогда, если на клиентах написать site.my.org, то будет round robin, т.е они будут подключатся то туда то туда, если хотите сделать active-backup, то пропишите в имя зоны 1 айпи и настройте время минимальное время кэширования, тогда, когда у вас откажет основной канал то  оперативно меняете запись на резервный айпи.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал с помощью обычного скрипта,правда, под Юникс.

Ping 1 раз в сек. основного канала, если ответ отрицательный, поднимаем второй канал, и переписывем таблицу маршрутизации. Как только канал восстановлен, восстанавливаем прежние настройки. Под винду, думаю, можно соорудить с помощью Шелла для Виндовс.

Comment: А можно было бы всего лишь указать метрику дефолтного маршрута.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Если не будет других предложений, то попробую с помощью шелла. И еще одно, если Вас не затруднит, то подскажите какую-нибудь толковую литературу по PowerShell (желательно с примерами).

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx http://www.robvanderwoude.com/powershellexamples.php  http://www.johndcook.com/PowerShellCookbook.html